# Maps API is not returning correct location (says that it is returning 'Approximate' location)

Tags: api, maps, geocode

We are passing a post code to the maps API and google is calculating the lat and lng co-ordinates.

However, these are not returning the correct location.

If i was to type this post code into the standard google maps webpage (maps.google.com), then the correct location is returned.

Why would this be?